# Google script trigger 'from Spreadsheet' not available

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I've successfully created picklists from a Google sheet into a Google form following a tutorial (http://wafflebytes.blogspot.com/2016/10/google-script-create-drop-down-list.html) and Google's documentation, however I do not have the option to set a trigger on the Event 'From spreadsheet', as laid out in the the tutorials/documentation, so I must be missing a step and haven't been able to figure out what it is.

The result is that the options are not automatically updating and must be manually pushed. I would like to enable the options to be refreshed on open.

I do not have the option to updateForm + from spreadsheet, as pictured in those resources.

From tutorial

[image: Configuration from tutorial]

My options

[image: My only options]

What step am I missing? Or is this possibly a permissions issue (I am not owner of the documents, but I tried to reproduce this in docs I own and ran into the same issue)?

NOTE: I have not posted my script here because it's nearly identical to the one linked to in the tutorial.

Update:

I'm beginning more and more to think it has to do with our OAuth configurations or permissions. I even updated the manifest to explicitly authorize forms and sheets, but I'm still not offered sharing permissions. I will have our admin check in on [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority) but if anybody has had experience in these matters, I'm all ears.

Comment: There is no link to the tutorial.

Comment: The tutorial is using a trigger from the spreadsheet. Do you have the option to run a trigger from the spreadsheet?

Comment: Just updated with the link to the tutorial. ... @JasonAllshorn, alas no I have no option offered in the dropdowns - only the ones pictured with 'Update form' + 'from form'

Answer (score 2):

Since your options shows "From form", you are working on a project bounded to a form instead of the one that you created from your spreadsheet which is the one bounded to spreadsheet.

Rather than missing a tutorial step it could be that you had several script projects open at the same time and you are looking at the wrong one.

Reference

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Hi - my apologies for somehow missing the link to the tutorial -- I just added it now. It starts with opening the code editor from the sheet, after which point the author is allowed to reference the spreadsheet from the trigger list, but I only seem to be able to listen in the scope of the form :/

Comment: @LindsayMoss I reworded my answer.

Comment: Hi Ruben, thanks but wouldn't that mean my script wouldn't work at all? It does work, but only when I "press play" (as I have no other available triggers/listeners)

Comment: @LindsayMoss No, that doesn't mean that. I suggest you to start over from scratch.